# Android convert complete view to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmapimage

can i get the whole `linearlayout` or other layouts converted to bitmap.
my code is this :

```
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_parent);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

the problem is if layout is larger than the screen size only i get whats on screen & not the whole contents e.g. textview etc. which are currently not on screen but are part of layout.

Any suggestions geeks out there.
this is way to urgent and important.

Comment: what do you mean by "is larger than the screen size" ? i assume that you have a `ScrollView` , in this case , you should apply your code on your `ScrollView` and not the `LinearLayout`

Comment: `view.getDrawingCache();` AFAIK the drawing cache is only for the visible part of the screen. You won't be able to get a bitmap of the whole layout that way. And honestly, considering that stuff is not on the screen the whole measure/layout cycle haven't happen, so you won't get it.

Comment: thnx for your advice. bcoz of the limitations u mentioned i m now printing data by fetching it from database !!!!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that will be Easy tho. assuming that you trying to Save the view to a bitmap. 
well here is my full saving method check it out and see how it works.

```
void Save() {
    if (null != view.getDrawable()) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        save = view.getDrawingCache();
        final File myDir = new File(folder);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        final Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
          file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                    "Something Went Wrong check if you have Enough Memory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        final Toast tst = Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                "Please Select An Image First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();
    }
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

here is the folder name that the image will be saved to.

```
    String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/StyleMe";
```

you can change StyleMe to become your app name or anything u like.
and here is my file just declare both in under your class name. or just add them inside the method `static File file;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a size before getting the Bitmap. Use the following code to get Bitmap and try.

```
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_parent);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()); 
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```